Error while processing Video using Ffmpeg
I am facing a weird error in FFMPG while doing any operation of a particular video. I did a lot of R&D but did not found any solution regarding this. Can anyone of you please look into it, it will be so kind.
here is a command i am using to mute the video, but end up with the following error.
fun videoMuteCmd(
    filePath: Uri,
    outputPath: String,
): Array<String> {
    return arrayOf(
        "-y", "-i", filePath.toString(),
       
        "-c", "copy", "-an", outputPath
    )
}

ERROR

: LogMessage{executionId=3010, level=AV_LOG_ERROR,
text='[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
@ 0xb400007c1243e000] Multiple mdhd?
'}
: LogMessage{executionId=3010, level=AV_LOG_ERROR,
text='[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
@ 0xb400007c1243e000] error reading header
'}
LogMessage{executionId=3010, level=AV_LOG_ERROR,
text='/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
Video/VID-20240510-WA0037.mp4: Invalid data found when
processing input
'}

Please look into this error and please suggest the possible fix.
